# Is there ln in hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there `ln -s` in hadoop HDFS?

For instance:

I have 10 files in HDFS

`/user/hadoop/input`, which is `1.txt, 2.txt ... 10.txt`

Another dir in HDFS is `/user/hadoop/test`

I just wanna copy 1 file from  `/user/hadoop/input/1.txt` to  `/user/hadoop/test/1.txt`.

The simplest way is use `hadoop dfs -cp /user/hadoop/1.txt /user/hadoop/test`.

But it cost more time and disk space. Is there a way like shell such as `hadoop dfs -ln /user/hadoop/1.txt /user/hadoop/test/1.txt` ?

Comment: There are symbolic links in a somewhat newer version, what version are you using?

Comment: the version of my hadoop is 1.0.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HDFS supports Symbolic links. Check [1](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/), [2](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileContext.html#createSymlink%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean%29), [3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-245), [4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6421) for more details. So, it can be done using Java API, but never came across a CLI for the same.

Comment: Thxs for your reply. I found the Java API yesterday too. Is there any tools that use the API can do this. I don't wanna repeat myself:)

Comment: Its pretty crappy there is no CLI way to do this :(

Comment: [HADOOP-10020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10020) and [HADOOP-10052](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10052) disabled symlinks since 2.2.0. It says 'temporarily' until 2.3.0 but I see it is still disabled in 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0. It's quite disappointing that cloudera just removed a feature

Comment: It's still disabled as of December 2016 https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Is-hdfs-symbolic-link-available/m-p/12172#M455