# Hive - Move existing warehouse location on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, data-warehouse, hortonworks-data-platform

I have an HDP cluster we've been using for some time now and existing dbs and tables in Hive full of data

We decided to change the location of hive's data warehouse on HDFS from `/apps/hive/warehouse` to a custom directory

I changed `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` in `hive-site.xml` and the change is taken into account when we create new dbs/tables

However existing content is still in `/apps/hive/warehouse`.
Is there a way to move it without breaking Hive or re-importing everything ?

Comment: Seems there is no support for symbolic links in HDFS till the Hadoop version 2.2.0. more info is here.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401118/is-there-ln-in-hadoop-hdfs

Comment: thanks, that was indeed a possibility, however i'd prefer to have Hive move the warehouse and adapt the metastore accordingly or have a way to do it manually without breaking everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did something like this a in the past. You would need to do a hack and update a value in the HIVE metastore directly:

1. Connect to MySQL or other DB with HIVE metastore;
2. use hive;
3. select * from DBS;
4. update DBS set DB_LOCATION_URI = 'NEW_LOCATION' where DB_ID = UPDATED_DB_ID;
5. restart metastore/hiveserver2 - do not remember how

Comment: For 5. I have ambari.
I suppose I also have to move the data in HDFS ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to do "hadoop fs -mv /apps/hive/warehouse/DB_NAME /NEW_WARESHOUSEPATH/DB_NAME"