# how to create a symlink on a hdfs cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, symlink

I try to use "createSymlink" function to create a symlink on hadoop 2.6.0, but it showed "Symlinks not supported"!

Does the hadoop hdfs not support the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there ln in hadoop HDFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401118/is-there-ln-in-hadoop-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

According to this jira task it is disabled

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10019